# Error when reading in a .dat file from a website in R

Tags: r, proxy

I face a problem in R to read-in a .dat file from a website. I know that a similar post has been posted already, but the answer regarding proxy settings haven't helped me, therefore sharing my code and the error adjacently:

```
data.2 <- read.table(file="http://stat.ethz.ch/Teaching/Datasets/WBL/cbe.dat")
```

> Error in file(file, "rt") :    cannot open the connection to
> 'http://stat.ethz.ch/Teaching/Datasets/WBL/cbe.dat' In addition:
> Warning message: In file(file, "rt") :   URL
> 'https://stat.ethz.ch/Teaching/Datasets/WBL/cbe.dat': status was
> 'Couldn't resolve proxy name'

Some people from class were able to have it inserted to R without any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually just solved it now when simply downloading the .dat file and saving it locally.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You are sitting behind a Firewall, in which the default port for insecure HTTP traffic (80) is blocked. Please contact your IT administrator or use another internet connection.

However, `ethz.ch` provides internal https service as well:

```
read.table(file="https://stat.ethz.ch/Teaching/Datasets/WBL/cbe.dat")
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. The thing is that I access it from a private network and this hasn't caused any problems in the past. I also tried other .dat files from other websites and there it has worked.

Any ideas what could have been changed?

Comment: @JeffreySachs I revised my answer. Try to use `https` instead of `http`

Comment: Unfortunately still throws the same error...

Comment: I now de-installed and re-installed RStudio, which resulted in showing me a new error: Error in file(file, "rt") : 
  cannot open the connection to 'https://stat.ethz.ch/Teaching/Datasets/WBL/cbe.dat'
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  URL 'https://stat.ethz.ch/Teaching/Datasets/WBL/cbe.dat': status was 'Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates'

Comment: Are you inside eduroam? There are root certificates which need to be installed.

Comment: No - I'm in my private network at home. Not connected to eduroam...